# JScrollPane and sizing issues

Tags: java, swing, layout, user-interface, jpanel

I am having quite a problem in regards to a proper way to handle 'packing' a JPanel and allowing a scroll bar.

I left out a bit of the code, but I believe what is provided should suffice.

The issue, is that the JScrollBar either doesn't show up, or can't be interacted with (if I set the scroll bar to always have the vertical bar).

Here is an image depicting this:

![No Scroll Bar Present][1]

The ProjectPanel (extends JPanel) are of fixed size and, as you can see, extend farther than the visible view port. There is NO way of getting the calculated height of the JPanel (ProjectSelector), as the ProjectPanels can also be transitioned as so:

![They need to fill as a grid][2]

If anyone could help provide some insight on how to do this, that would be great. As of now, I would like at all costs not to use an external API, as that would cause more harm than good.

**Question:**

How can I set the height for the preferred size to be 'flexible', so as I add components it can expand? If that wouldn't be ideal / no possible, how could I properly allow the JScrollPane to show all components of the JPanel efficiently?

Comment: Don't set the preferred size selector. The scroll pane is using this as part of its determination of when to display its scroll bars

Comment: @MadProgrammer, if I do not, then the Flow Layout organizes them horizontally. I can provide a sample image to show you, but it won't work. I don't want any horizontal scrolling available.

Comment: ie. let the LayoutManager determine the preferredSize of the panel.

Comment: If I don't specify the width of the panel: http://i.imgur.com/a9fIJd2.png

Comment: @Legend I was about to address that, take a look at [WrapLayout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), which fixes this problem

Comment: @camickr Thanks, was going to add that ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would like to not use an external API, source or even jar. I also mentioned as to why I can't "let the LayoutManager determine the preferredSize", because it can't.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a pain, I'm just trying to deal with one.

Comment: `I would like to not use an external API, source or even jar` - Your code doesn't work because that is not the way a JScrollPane was designed to work. So you have a couple of choices a) leave the code as it is, b) rewrite the scrollpane to handle your situation, c) use a layout manager that handles your requirement.

Comment: Well, the scroll pane is meant to work off the size of the panel. If there was a way I could 'pack' the panel, just as you would a JFrame, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You could also write your own layout manager

Comment: No, the scrollpane works off the preferred size of the component in the viewport. LayoutManagers are designed to dynamically determine the preferred size of a component. You could always add a component listener to you panel and manually recalculate the size of the panel, but then you are just reinventing the wheel by creating your own version of a layout manager. Good luck.

Comment: +1 nice screen_shots, please this is Nimbus on Win8 ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I do not, then the Flow Layout organizes them horizontally

Maybe you should be using a GridLayout.

If not then you can try the [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) which is a FlowLayout that wraps to a new line as required.

Comment: The problem with the GridLayout, which I had originally, is that it doesn't maintain the inner-panel sizes. It also, has defined columns, which wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I just realized it after I posted and saw your two images.

Comment: I'll probably just make my own, but looking how the Wrap Layout worked will help. Thanks for the answer and time. Sorry about this huge inconvenience. This program is for a portfolio, so the less external APIs I use, the more credible my work is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a different layout, why don't you try [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)? It is a very powerful and flexible layout manager.

See a detailed example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851946/679982).

From that link, rewrite the `initUI` method to see the behavoir interesting to your problem:

```
public void initUI() {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setJMenuBar(initMenuBar());
    this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(mainPanel = initMainPanel()));
    this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    this.pack();        
}
```